# Camel Wiretap Error Handling

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am new to camel (v 2.10.0) and searching for a problem that i have due to exceptions that we throw in routes which are called by wireTap().

PROBLEM: is that when exception are thrown from wiretap routes then error handling do not run for these exceptions. When we change calls to direct "to()" calls then we have proper error handling. WireTap as per my understanding should also use same ErrorHandlerBuilder that is working for other routes in same RouteBuilder class.

We have our ErrorHandlerBuilder, that is configured per camel context as (in OSGI blueprints)

```
<camelContext id="ourHandlerContext" trace="false" errorHandlerRef="ourErrorHandlerBuilder"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
 <routeBuilder ref="ourHandlerRouteBuilder"/>

</camelContext>
```

But our camel routes are in Java ourHandlerRouteBuilder class configure() method have something like this:

```
from("direct-vm:start").routeId("start")          
    .wireTap("direct-vm:wiretap_exception")
    .to("direct-vm:endroute_last");

    from("direct-vm:wiretap_exception").routeId("wiretap_exception")
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            throw new Exception("I AM EXCEPTION");
        }
    })
    ;

    from("direct-vm:endroute_last").routeId("endroute_last")
    .process(new Processor() {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            throw new Exception("I AM ALSO EXCEPTION");
        }
    })
    ;
```

The "I AM EXCEPTION" never caught alone when thrown but when i throw also "I AM ALSO EXCEPTION" then i can see it in ErrorHandler.

We have our some complex translators over these exceptions to translate to some http error code that i think not necessary here to share.

But from above scenario if some body can share his thoughts will be helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wireTap` runs asynchronously thus you cant wait to catch its exceptions. If you want to run it synchronously and wait for possible exceptions, you can use `enrich` instead.

Something like this:

```
    .enrich("direct-vm:wiretap_exception", new AggregationStrategy() {
        @Override
        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
            return oldExchange;
        }        
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are right but i want error handling to be reused in wireTap also, when i define a DefaultErrorHandler in routebuilder class and add onException() with inline processor it comes to that code. But we have overwritten ErrorHandlerSupport and ErrorHandlerBuilderSupport classes to translate Exception in some HTTP Codes. ErrorHandlerSupport differs from DefaultErrorHandler in such a way that it adds Error handling without onException in routes but per Camel context but not for wireTaps. But when DefaultErrorHandler is used in RouteBuilder class then all routes are handled.

Comment: Hi again, after a few debugs and going throw each class i got it, Exceptions are handled properly but due to wiretap main route ends very early and user get the response, but the error-handler work correctly and do all processing correctly but no response to send again as its already set.

Answer (score 0):

I am also experiencing a similar issue. If an exception throws inside the wiretapped subroute "anotherRoute", the onException block does not executed. What should be the solution to create custom error handling in the wiretapped route? Camel version: 3.1.0

```
from("rest:POST:/order")
  .wiretap("direct:anotherRoute");
  
from("direct:anotherRoute")
 .onException(Exception.class)
   .doErrorHandlingThings(...)
   .handled(true)
   .stop()
 .end()
 .process(dobusinessLogicNormally);
```

However when placing the onException() block outside of wiretapped route to a global scope it works as should.

```
 onException(Exception.class)
   .doErrorHandlingThings(...)
   .handled(true)
   .stop()
 .end();


from("rest:POST:/order")
  .wiretap("direct:anotherRoute");

from("direct:anotherRoute")
  .exceptionThrow()
```